# Terminal Settings: Replace error message of alias

Tags: linux, macos, terminal, zshrc, aliases

Wassup Guys,

I have made a few aliases inside my terminal settings for some handy commands.
However, one of the aliases is using docker and when the docker engine is not started, it prints the following error:
(Obivously I do not always use docker when I use the terminal)

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is
> the docker daemon running?

[image: errormsg]

My question is, if I can edit my alias inside my .zshrc settings so I can print something else instead this of this long message? Like a Simple hello.
Below are my settings:
GNU nano 2.0.6          File: .zshrc

```
alias kill="docker kill $(docker ps -q) || print Wassup G"
alias sail='[ -f sail ] && bash sail || bash vendor/bin/sail'
export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$(pyenv root)/shims:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib -L/usr/local/opt/bzip2/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include -I/usr/local/opt/bzip2/include"
```

[image]

Comment: Please do not post text output as images - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Especially not in that terrible contrast which makes it barely readable. Copy it as formatted text into the question.

Comment: Anyway, this is arguably off-topic for Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not questions about using or setting up Linux. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: I've added the code

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. It's a shell issue. The real problem is that you have aliased `kill` which is an existing standard command. That is a very very bad idea as many existing scripts and programs will use `kill`. Which is exactly what is happening when the shell login occurs. Change the name of the alias.